# bind function and entry box HELP for getting user input

Tags: python, tkinter

i am creating a game in python with tkinter. what i want to do is when i press enter i want my ans to be matched by correct answer and entry box to be empited. but when i press enter key, nothing happens.

```
class Easy(tk.Frame):
        operations=['+', '-', '*']
        a=random.randint(1,15)
        b=random.randint(1,15)
        score=0

        count=0
        random.shuffle(operations)
        op=operations[0]
        chances=0
        def startgame(self,event):

            while self.chances==3:
                break

            self.checkans()
        def checkans(self):


            if self.op=='+':
                ans=self.a+self.b
            if self.op=='-':
                ans=self.a-self.b
            if self.op=='*':
                ans=self.a*self.b

            if self.chances>3:
                e.focus_set()
                if e.get()==ans:
                    self.score+=1
                else:
                    self.chances+=1
                e.delete(0,tk.END)
                label.configure(text=(self.a,self.op,self.b))
                scorelabel.configure(text=('score',score))
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
            label=tk.Label(self,text='Easy level starts')
            label.pack()
            scorelabel=tk.Label(self,text= 'score=0')
            scorelabel.pack()
            label=tk.Label(self,text=(self.a,self.op,self.b))
            label.pack()
            e=tk.Entry(self)
            e.bind('<Return>',self.startgame)
            e.pack()
            e.focus_set()
```

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your `startgame` function has an infinite loop that will never exit, since `self.chances` will never change inside of that loop.

Comment: Can you explain how can i access the chances? Should i use global chances and then use self.chances?